# FME Many to One to append attribute and not create new feature

Tags: fme-form

I have a land cadastre spatial table where the Land_no is unique for each parcel. I am joining this to a non-spatial mssql search where the property number is repeated whenever there is more than one owner.

Wherever the prop_no is repeated, I want the FeatureMerger to append any extra owner info to the existing OBJECT rather than create a new geometric as it has to be unique by Land_no.

The first example below shows what I would like to see
[image]

So the Name_IDs would be '8678|8679'

I have the following settings in my FeatureMerger -this also shows the section of the model and the output from the SQLCreator
[image]

Can I get it to append the values in the Owner_Name and Name_IDs fields without having to (somehow) manipulate the SQL to do this .

A further issue is that if there are more than 2 owners then the name should be

```
Albert Einsteen and Martin Luther and others
```

Not

```
Albert Einsteen and Martin Luther and Sigmund Freud
```

But the Name ID's should have the value for all three - so '1234|1456|1789'

**UPDATE**
Here's the model with some relevant parameters exposed. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approaches given in @Mark Irelard 's answer are great. To add to this, here is the process that I would use to get the desired results as well as a visual of the workspace:

[image]

By clicking on "Generate List" in the FeatureMerger, this enables to keep only one feature per Requestor, and add each matched Supplier's attributes in lists, which can be lated processed and concatenated.
You can concatenate all the Name_Ids store in the list for each property in a single attribute with a "|" separator. 
A tester allows to verify if an attribute _OwnerList{2}.Owner_Name is missing in the list, in other words, if the list contains only 1 or 2 names. Then the process is split in two to treat the special case with 3 or more names and add " and others" after the second name.

If you need to similarly concatenate values for other attributes, simply add more ListConcatenators for the desired attributes. You can also select "All attributes" in the "Generate List - Add to List" section of the FeatureMerger if you need several of them.

Comment: Thank you - can you send me the fmw? it seems perfect and I'll test it once I get back to work next week.

Comment: Here is the Google Drive link to the file : [LandOwners.fmw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m0_hgyZ9GTwtvz2yW7M9XbjklvZGiRK3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That works brilliantly but I am getting duplicate records in the final tab file where anything with more than one owner is repeated. The model is in the following GDrive link -what am I doing wrong? https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h0e2DxKWCQaGjx_O0HRaEKzBjy6eHoFR and see Property_Update_DUPLICATE_RecordIssue.fmw

Comment: I'll have to check this out in 2 days. In the meanwhile, I am wondering, you seem to have other FeatureMergers and supplier tables in your workspace, did you check "Generate List" for those ones too?

Comment: No we don't need lists for those, only the 2 fields (Name ID's and Owner names) need to be concatenated.

Comment: Okay, I suspected that maybe one of those tables contained several rows per property and if Process duplicate suppliers is checked, then the data may have been duplicated there. Maybe simply adding a DuplicateRemover before the writer could help?

Comment: I tried but it removes more than expected. I'll update the question with a screen grab as that may help since you don't seem to be able to access the fmw for a couple of days. We should have 21,080 records but end up with 32k without the remover and 16k with the remover.

Comment: @GeorgeC What is the role of the StringSearcher? You seem to be sending the data twice - though the stringSearcher and through the list concatenators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95564/discussion-between-fsimardgis-and-georgec).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can check the option to Generate List. That will create a list (an FME data structure with multiple values for each attribute) on the existing geometry. At that point use a ListConcatenator to join all those values together into a regular attribute.

For the ID list use a | as a separator character, for the name list, use the word "and" (although it says "character" I think "characters" should be fine)

The owner name issue is an interesting one. You could choose to either deal with it after the fact or during the list creation/concatenation.

To deal with it after the fact, some form of regular expression might be in order. Like use a StringSearcher and extract everything up to (and including) the second " and ". Then just concatenate "others" to the end.

The deal with it during the list, maybe (thinking off the top of my head) use a ListElementCounter to count how many parts there are to the list. If it's just two then use a ListConcatenator. If it's three or more, then perhaps an AttributeCreator to concatenate "list.name{0} and list.name{1} and others"