# FME Repeat features when a record matches an expression

Tags: fme-form

I am working on automating the production of a land/parcel spatial table based on a state supplied cadastre (property layer) and injects from internal mssql systems. See this question for some further background [FME Many to One to append attribute and not create new feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327059/fme-many-to-one-to-append-attribute-and-not-create-new-feature)

When we have a parcel that is 0BUP48937 or 0SP117963 the SQL extract will have 1SP117963, 2SP117963 etc to match the number of different properties that exist within the parcel.

I currently match the state cadastre based on lotplan which then only incorporates the parcel with 0SP117963. How can I get FME to follow a logic like below

a - Where Lotplan starts with 0, match to the data from MSSQL (ex
   0SP117963)

b - then rather than rejecting the ones that start with 1,
   2, 3 etc (and have the same plan no) create a new polygon the same as 0SP117963

c -set the
   lotplan as 1SP117963 and then inject the rest of the relevant
   attribution.

So the table will be something like
[image]

The dataset does have Lot_num and Plan_num separately so the search for all records which have Lot_num=0 could also work...happy to also try a different logic if anyone can suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the ID structure is for 0SP117963, 1SP117963, 2SP117963, etc (i.e. Is it always SP? Does it always end in 6 digits) but logic suggests removing the nSP part, or extracting the 117963 part and carrying out the match on that alone.

Then you'll get multiple matches for 117963 and can choose how to deal with that in the FeatureJoiner/FeatureMerger(?) by creating multiple features and/or creating a list and exploding it.